# Trying to clear the unmanaged code in my Org using destructiveChanges.xml

Tags: destructivechanges.xml

I want to delete the unmanaged code present in my org using salesforce migration tool.While undeploying the components i'm facing a lot of errors like you cannot delete the following components as they are referred in some other components.
eg: xyz page is linked with some Custom tab or link .
The dependency checker in salesforce doesn't seem to look beyond 1 level deep.

I cannot go and remove every dependency manually.Is there anyway undeployment can be achieved using destructivechanges.xml?
Or is there any hierarchy which i should follow to delete the components in multiple steps.

Answer (score 1):

This is a tricky one, and you are right: it's a very tedious process.

The way I have done it last time was starting from a base destructiveChanges and iterating over on every error, by adding a components based on the failure/output for that deployment attempt. If I remember correctly the order looked something like:

1) Pages
2) Components
3) Apex Classes
4) Workflows
5) Fields

If you do this and want to keep track of your final sequence please let me know. I'd like to write some script to automate it at some point.

Comment: hey..! thanks for the reply.But  mainly i was facing errors while undeploying pages which are linked with custom buttons or links, fields which are referred in some custom formula fields.

Comment: I want to remove those dependencies using my script.Don't want to remove the buttons first and thn delete the pages using script.

Comment: You are right. I am afraid removal of custom links/buttons cannot be easily scripted. I suggest to get rid of them all first, then you can iterate over the destructiveChanges.xml

Comment: while undeploying the objects, I got this error objects/Loan_Product__c.object -- Error: This custom field is referenced elsewhere in salesforce.com. : Filtered Lookup. This custom object definition is referenced elsewhere in salesforce.com.  Remove the usage and try again. : Workflow Rule-01Q15000000F5P1.

Comment: Do you have any idea how this can be handled ?

Comment: Check fields of type lookup within Load_Product__c and objects referring to it. For each lookup remove the filter clicking "Clear Filter Criteria"

Comment: Removing components at first is not possible as they are referred in pages usually.

Comment: Yep, my mistake!

Comment: I'm working on this undeployment thing from last one month and couldn't find an automated way to clear my org.
Can you suggest me anything that can help me in this.

Comment: can i remove filtered lookups using destructiveChanges.xml ?

Comment: no you can't unfortunately.